# How to set request field of a BundleEntry of FHIR Model

Tags: python-3.x, hl7-fhir

I am using https://pypi.org/project/fhir.resources/ and my goal is to set request, taht is:

```
new_bundle_entry = BundleEntry()
patient_bundle_entry.resource = new_patient.sh_patient // as Patient
patient_bundle_entry.request = xxx
```

where xxx should codify :

```
"request": {
   "method": "POST",
}
```

What is the class that I should use to instanciate the above and set the attribute request?

Please, any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
identif ="identifier=http://hl7.eu/fhir/ig/gk/identifier/"+pilot_id+"/patient|"+user_id
                method_description = {
                        "method": "POST",
                         "url": "Patient",
                        "ifNoneExist": identif
                }
                req = BundleEntryRequest(**method_description)
                p_bundle_entry.request = req
```